# New neo4j version 2.0 enforced UNION cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Due to the new changes in neo4j 2.0.0 I was forced to come up with this query (instead of a query that used 'r?:' operator):

```
start s=node(404374) 
match (s)<-[:SESSION]-(uv:_UrlVisit)
optional match (uv)-[r:REFERRER]->() 
with uv, r where r IS NULL 
return uv 
UNION
start s=node(404374) 
match (s)<-[:SESSION]-(uv:_UrlVisit)-[:REFERRER]->(uvp:_UrlVisit)-[:SESSION]->(s2) 
where ID(s)<>ID(s2) 
return uv;
```

Is there any way this query can be written in one shot without UNION?

Comment: What happens if you put the entire optional pattern in the optional match clause, `OPTIONAL MATCH uv-[:REFERRER]->(:_UrlVisit)-[:SESSION]->(s2)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on @jjaderberg's suggestion this query returns the right results:

```
start s=node(404374) 
match (s)<-[:SESSION]-(uv:_UrlVisit)
optional match (uv)-[r:REFERRER]->(:_UrlVisit)-[:SESSION]->(s2) 
with s,uv,r,s2
where r IS NULL OR ID(s)<>ID(s2) return uv;
```